# WPA2 WiFi password constrained to 5 or 13 characters

Tags: wireless, networking, network-manager

First of all, I found both of these pages:

[Wifi only accepts passwords of 5 or 13 characters](https://askubuntu.com/questions/304460/wifi-only-accepts-passwords-of-5-or-13-characters)

[Cannot change Wifi settings, stuck on WEP Security](https://askubuntu.com/questions/459466/cannot-change-wifi-settings-stuck-on-wep-security)

Both look similar to my problem, but seem associated with WEP, not WPA or WPA2.  I've double-checked that my WiFi router is set for WPA2, and it is.

I do have a (perhaps rather obvious) workaround, which is to set a 13 character WiFi password on my router.  I would rather have a longer WiFi password.  I could also set 5 character password; maybe "PwnMe" would work? :)

If anyone's interested in investigating/solving the problem, I'm happy to try things.

I'm running Lubuntu 12.04, and the issue has just started to affect me.  I have seen the issue before in 14.04 on similar-ish hardware (in terms of age and capability).  It didn't appear in 12.04 until I applied a recent (last week or so?) update.  My guess is someone ported some changes from 14.04 down in to 12.04 because it's also an LTS release?

I'm hoping that I'll get an e-mail if others reply here...  I will try to monitor, too.

All thoughts and suggestions gratefully received...

Comment: Go to `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` and delete all files that refer to this connection. Then try again to set up a Wi-Fi connection.

Comment: Cheers, Jos.  I will try it later.

Comment: Jos,  I should let you know that worked, after multiple deletion/re-addition of the WiFi network.  Eventually, I ended up changing the Wifi password to a 13 character one.  After being set like that, it let me change it to a longer (or shorter) one.  It's working now.  Thanks for your help with it.

Comment: OK, I will add my remark as an answer. Please accept my answer so this question gets marked as answered.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` and delete all files that refer to this connection. Then try again to set up a Wi-Fi connection